# How to download file into memory without writing the file to the system or without creating the file in a directory using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128805/node-js-how-to-download-file-into-memory-without-writing-the-file-to-the-system), but using javascript. I want to download the file into javascript memory and then add the file content to a file input so that I can upload that again. I have written a function to access the file.

```
function fileDownload(url, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET", url, true);
                xhr.send();
                xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status != 200) { // analyze HTTP status of the response
                console.log(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // e.g. 404: Not Found
            } else { // show the result
            callback(xhr.response)
  }
};
            }
```

So xhr supports the response type as text, arraybuffer, blob and document. So which type should I use? I want to support all types of files. Can I use blob?In that case how can I assign it to an input type of file. Please help.

Comment: If you are uploading file via Ajax, then you do not need to put it into file input.

Comment: @Justinas      I am working on an existing application. So I want it that way. My question is that is it possible to download file content into memory using javascript?

Comment: Download from server? Yes. Put `<input type="file">` content dynamically? No.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883749/dynamically-adding-files-to-a-input

Comment: @Justinas      Yes. But I can dynamically add the file input with the file value right?